# Is there ANY backup tool that can handle 256 path length limit on NTFS?

Tags: windows-7, windows, ntfs, windows-backup, incremental-backup

Is there ANY backup tool that can handle 256 path length limit on NTFS ?

I'm not talking about a sync or filecopy tool like robocopy,
but an incremental backup tool like cobian backup (which cannot handle it).

Comment: rsync-based tools

Comment: I have seen some shellscripts, using hard and soft links, that make rsync into an incremental backup tool.

Is there anything similar using windows scripting ?

Comment: you can do exactly the same thing on windows--using cygwin.

Comment: I guess your right. It's not the answer I was looking for ( too much work installing flaky cygwin and some dodgy script :-) ).

If you summarize this into an answer, I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Are you sure Cobian cannot handle it -- even if you enter all paths with the `\\?\ ` prefix?

Comment: I will try that.
I just dragged and dropped the root folders from Explorer.

Comment: Prefixed all source folders with \\?\, and then marked all files as archiavble, but still cobian boletus copies a few hundred files less than robocopy /E, for the same source.

Comment: I've had a similar problem with deep paths, which was a limitation of Windows, the work around was to mount/subst some deep directory so Windows could access the files that deep.

Comment: http://www.areca-backup.org/

was the ONLY tool that worked flawlessly with > 256 path length to external USB drives.

it was not so user fiendly, so I ended up with a compromise, using Cobian as main backup tool, and RoboMirror/robocopy for plain syncing of the folders with extremely long paths.

Comment: [Cobian Backup's v8 Release Notes](http://www.educ.umu.se/~cobian/cbnew.htm) indicate that `MAX_PATH` should no longer be an issue, and it should handle 32K-length Unicode paths.  If it's not backing everything up, that's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I am not familiar with Cobian.  Presently I use a simple script run from a CentOS vmware machine running in my Windows 7 host workstation to handle long path values:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo Backup Started `date` >> ~/backuplog
mkdir /mnt/hgfs/g/Backups/`date +%Y%m%d`
tar -cvf /mnt/hgfs/g/Backups/`date +%Y%m%d`/docs.data.tar /mnt/hgfs/c/Users/username
7za a -t7z -m0=lzma -mx=9 -mfb=64 -md=32m -ms=on /mnt/hgfs/g/Backups/`date +%Y%m%d`.7za /mnt/hgfs/g/Backups/`date +%Y%m%d`
mv /mnt/hgfs/g/Backups/`date +%Y%m%d`.7za /mnt/hgfs/g/Backups/`date +%Y%m%d`
rm /mnt/hgfs/g/Backups/`date +%Y%m%d`/*.tar
echo Backup Completed `date` >> ~/backuplog
```

For an incremental script, you may want to look at the following pages:

- [Linux / UNIX Tar Full and Incremental Tape Backup Shell Script](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/backup/tar-full-incremental-tape-backup-script/)
- [[bash] Simple backup (cp) script but incremental](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/116760-bash-simple-backup-cp-script-but-incremental.html)